# I need to submit additional fields added by append function by using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, append

I have met an obstacle concerning append fields submission by using ajax.

Here is the description of my problem.

My HTML form is

```
<div id="append-fields">
    <input name="firstName[]" id="firstName" value="john"></input>
    <input name="lastName[]" id="lastName" value="Doe"></input>
</div>
<button onclick="appendFunction()" type="button">Add a new row</button>
```

After clicking a button `add a new row` I get more two fields like this

```
    <div id="append-fields">
      <input name="firstName[]" id="firstName" value="anna"></input>
      <input name="lastName[]" id="lastName" value="Kondo"></input>
    </div>
```

Now I need to submit the following data with ajax

```
        firstName = 'john',lastName = 'Doe'
        firstName = 'anna',lastName = 'kondo'
```

But I get only one set of data like this

```
     firstName = 'john',lastName = 'Doe'
```

Here is myscript

```
        <script>
        insert = [];
        insert[0] = $("#firstName").val();
        insert[1] = $("#lastName").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myUrl',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {take:insert},
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#overlay').addClass("hidden");
                jQuery('#body').html(response);
            }
        });
   </script>
```

Here is my PHP

```
      function myUrl(){
         $data = $_POST["take"];
       }
```

Where is the mistake is?

Comment: You cannot (if you want things to ork correctly) have 2 `id` attributes with the same name like `id="firstName"` which you have once per added html block.

Comment: If you make those `id` unique you can then add them to your data structure in the ajax call

Comment: Alternatively use an `each.` on the class name and in that add data to your data structure in the ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use formdata

```
    var data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    data .append('extra', add_data);
```

or seriallize or seriallizeArray by class which I would seggust

```
var form_data = $('.post_these').serialize();
```

PS: post_these is input Field class

In PHP access by name

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
```

or when data is array create an object

```
$data= (object) $_POST['data'];
$data-YfirstName; // use this way
```

PS use this to debug, check in your controller what you recieve

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks! but I need to know how may i separate the field name from the value?       b'se the received data is like this firstName=john&lastName=Doe&firstName=anna&lastName=kondo

Answer (score 1):

You should not fetch your data values by ID because it's not possible to have more than one of the same ID elements.

Since you're using jquery anyway, use `$('form').serialize()` or `$('form').serializeArray()` for array output to fetch all the form inputs and it's values. You will have to wrap those inputs in a form element before you do this though.

Or as suggested above, loop over the elements manually and get the values like that.